# Gerar número aleatório em um intervalo dado pelo usuário - Java/Android

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando gerar um número aleatório num intervalo dado pelo usuário.
O Android Studio não aponta erro, no entanto o app não gera nenhum valor. O que pode estar errado? Desde já agradeço!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView generate = findViewById(R.id.Generator);

        generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText minValue = findViewById(R.id.Min);
                EditText maxValue = findViewById(R.id.Max);
                TextView finalValue = findViewById(R.id.Value);

                String minString = String.valueOf(minValue);
                String maxString = String.valueOf(maxValue);

                int min = Integer.parseInt(minString);
                int max = Integer.parseInt(maxString);

                if (max > min) {
                    Random randGen = new Random();
                    int generate = randGen.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                    String genString = String.valueOf(generate);
                    finalValue.setText(genString);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite, você precisa recuperar os valores passados nos EditText

ao invés de usar:

```
  String minString = String.valueOf(minValue);
  String maxString = String.valueOf(maxValue);
```

Deixe:

```
            String minString = String.valueOf(minValue.getText());
            String maxString = String.valueOf(maxValue.getText());
```

Obs: Ao invés de usar um TextView como botão, por que não utiliza Button mesmo?

Comment: Se minha resposta foi útil, por favor aceite ela como resposta ao lado esquerdo e se possível marcá-la como útil.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

> o erro está aqui:

```
String minString = String.valueOf(minValue);
String maxString = String.valueOf(maxValue);
```

> Assim vc está recebendo apenas o edittext, é preciso converter o objeto em uma string usando .toString(). No seu caso, vc já pode pegar o int diretamente pelo toString(), eliminando algumas linhas de codigo.

```
int min = Integer.parseInt(minValue.getText.toString);
int max = Integer.parseInt(maxValue.getText.toString);
```